# Не запускается сервер в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Проблема в следующем. При попытке установки MySQL на компютер установка зависает на моменте Starting server и дальше ничего не происходит.5-й раз пытаюсь установить и всё бесполезно. В чем может быть проблема?Заранее спасибо)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите что за ошибка возникает именно на вашем этапе установки в окне просмотра событий установщика или в Log файлах операционной системы. Затем по ID или другим признакам вы сможете перейти к ее устранению. А если это не поможет, тогда воспользуйтесь "Центром справки и помощи" через меню или на официальном сайте программы. Типичная ошибка пользователей - использование пробела в названиях. А MySQL не может обрабатывать символ пробела в названии службы. Если это так, просто измените имя на одно без пробелов.

Comment: Спасибо))))))))